# Django Programming error column does not exist even after running migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I run `python manage.py makemigrations` and I get:
    No changes detected
Then, `python manage.py migrate` and I get:
    No migrations to apply.

Then, I try to push the changes to production:
    git push heroku master
    Everything up-to-date

Then, in production, I repeat the command:
    heroku run python manage.py migrate
    No migrations to apply.

Just in case, I run `makemigrations` in production:

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

WHY then I get a

```
ProgrammingError at ....

column .... does not exist
```

"No changes detected" means the database is coherent with the code. 
How can I debug this?¡?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Django migrations are recorded in your database under the 'django_migrations' table. This is how Django knows which migrations have been applied and which still need to be applied.

Have a look at django_migrations table in your DB. It may be that something went wrong when your migration was applied. So, delete the row in the table which has the migration file name that is related to that column that 'does not exist'. Then, try to re-run a migration.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the rollback feature? I naively tried this and ended up with a dependency history error and restored from the backup I had just created. Use this with some caution.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the rollback feature in the docs?

Comment: Wow, can't find it. I still advise caution using this answer but the closest thing I found is this script: https://gist.github.com/Jc2k/bacff3105653f3b28e84

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it existed either. Not sure why you received a dependency history error. Maybe it depends on Django version? Either way, this quick-fix should only be applied in development which should be clear...

Comment: Reversing migrations documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations

Answer (score 41):

I got the same problem (column not exist) but when I try to run `migrate` not with `makemigrations` (it is the same issue I believe)

- Cause: I removed the migration files and replaced them with single pretending intial migration file 0001 before running the migration for the last change
- Solution:

  1. Drop tables involved in that migration of that app (consider a backup workaround if any)
  2. Delete the rows responsible of the migration of that app from the table `django_migrations` in which migrations are recorded, This is how Django knows which migrations have been applied and which still need to be applied.

And here is how solve this problem:

- log in as postgres user (my user is called posgres):

  `sudo -i -u postgres`
- Open an sql terminal and connect to your database:

  `psql -d database_name`
- List your table and spot the tables related to that app:

  `\dt`
- Drop them (consider drop order with relations):

  `DROP TABLE tablename ;`
- List migration record, you will see migrations applied classified like so:

> id | app | name | applied
>   --+------+--------+---------+

```
SELECT * FROM django_migrations;
```

- Delete rows of migrations of that app (you can delete by id or by app, with app don't forget 'quotes'):

  `DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='yourapp';`
- log out and run your migrations merely (maybe run makemigrations in your case):

  `python manage.py migrate --settings=your.settings.module_if_any`

Note: it is possible that in your case will not have to drop all the tables of that app and not all the migrations, just the ones of the models causing the problem.

I wish this can help.

Comment: Had the same issue. Dropping tables and re-running migration in heroku console solved it. Thanks !

Comment: `DROP TABLE tablename ;` will erase all data in the app right?

Comment: @Florent it will remove the table itself (so yes data of that table will be erased)

Comment: With all these being said, dont forget to backup your data

Answer (score 13):

Here's what i tried and it worked:

- Go and add manually the column to your table
- run python manage.py makemigrations
- go back drop that column you added
- run python manage.py migrate

Comment: How do you add column manualy ?

Comment: use pgadmin if you're using postgres

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue - the error message appeared when I clicked on the model on the django-admin site. I solved it by commenting out the field in models.py, then running migrations. Following this I uncommented the field and re ran the migrations. After that the error message disappeared.

Comment: I removed all migration files and commenting out worked for me too.

Comment: @GraceBe I tried the same thing, but it doesnt seem to be helping...

Comment: the only solution that worked thanks

Answer (score 5):

My case might be a bit obscure, but if it helps someone, it is worth documenting here.

I was calling a function in one of my migrations, which imported a Model of said migration regularly, i.e.

```py
from myApp.models import ModelX
```

The only way models should be imported in migrations would be using e.g. RunPython:

```py
def myFunc(apps, schema_editor): 
    MyModel = apps.get_model('myApp 'MyModel')
```

and then calling that function like so:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(initialize_mhs, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

Additionally the original import worked until I modified the model in a later migration, making this error harder to locate.

Comment: Indeed, when renaming or removing fields it can be tricky importing models, especially when you have custom code manipulating those fields. This solution solves this.

Comment: PS: There is a typo: MyModel = apps.get_model('myApp 'MyModel') should be MyModel = apps.get_model('myApp', 'MyModel')

Answer (score 2):

Just remove corresponding row migrations for that model in 'django_migrations' model  in database.

And re run `python manage.py migrate app_name`

Answer (score 1):

So, I always run into this sort of problem, so today I decided to try and work it out at the database level. Thing is, I changed a model field name which `Django` didn't bother reflecting in a migration file. I only found out later when I ran into problems. I later looked at the migration files and discovered there was no migration for that change. But I didn't notice because I made other changes as well, so once I saw a migration file I was happy.
My advice. Create migration for each change one at a time. That way you get to see if it happened or not.

So here's my working through it in MySQL.

open mysql console.

```
show databases; # see all my dbs. I deleted a few
drop database <db-name>; # if needed
use <db-name>; # the database name for your django project
show tables; # see all tables in the database
DESCRIBE <table-name>; # shows columns in the database
SHOW COLUMNS FROM <db-name>; # same thing as above
ALTER TABLE <table-name> CHANGE <old-column-name> <new-column-name> <col-type>; # now I manually updated my column name
```

If you're using postgresql, just google the corresponding commands.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the Models for me, for some reason Django was adding '_id' to the end of my Foreign Key column. I had to explicitly set the related named to the Foreign Key. Here 'Cards' is the parent table and 'Prices' is the child table.

```
class Cards(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=45)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)   

class Prices(models.Model):
        unique_id = models.ForeignKey(Cards, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Works after changing to:

```
class Cards(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=45)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)   

class Prices(models.Model):
        unique_id = models.ForeignKey(Cards, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='unique_id')
```

Comment: Django always adds the '_id'. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

Answer (score 1):

When I get this error, my extreme way to solve it is to reset my database:

1. Reset your database

For Postgresql on Heroku:

Heroku > your_app > Resources > database > add-ons > click on your database and open it

For postgresql

settings > Reset database

2. Delete all files in your_app > migrations > `__pycache__` except `__init.py__`
3. Delete all files in your_app > migrations except `__pycache__` folder and `__init.py__`
4. Then run:

   `python manage.py makemigrations`

   `python manage.py migrate`

   `python manage.py createsuperuser`

type in to create your superuser, then run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate

python manage.py
```

If you are able to inspect your models from your admin section, then it should be all okay now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these answers with not much luck! What I did to have this problem solved with no harm was to go back through the migration files and find where the actual model was being created for the first time then manually add the field (in the column not being existed error message). Until if you run `makemigrations --dry-run` you get/see "No changes detected" and that worked. Basically, in my case, I had to carefully take my desired db changes back in time in proper migration file, rather creating a new migration now at the end of migration dependency chain.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the latest py file created after running the makemigrations command inside migrations folder of that particular app.
2. Inside class Migration there is a list attribute called 'operations'.
3. Remove the particular elements migrations.RemoveField(...).
4. Save and run `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

A easier solution to the problem is to make your models exactly like it is in the migration first. and run python manage.py migrate.

Then revert those changes

Run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

To check for which migrations are applied and which are not, use -:

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by deleting all migrations files *(Don't forget to make a backup)* and `python manage.py makemigrations` all of them into one clean file in development and pulling new files on the server. Before then I had dropped existing tables on the PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error for some reason when Django was looking for a column of type `ForeignKey` named `category_id` when the actual name in the database was `category`. I tried every Django solution I could imagine (renaming field, explicitly setting column name, etc.). **I didn't want to drop tables or rows as this was a production database.** The solution was simply to rename the column manually using SQL. In my case:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name 
RENAME COLUMN category TO category_id;
```

Make sure you backup your database, ensure this won't break any other applications consuming that particular table, and consider having a fallback column if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was being caused because someone had accessed the model globally in a module. The module was attempting to retrieve an instance of the model every time it was loaded. Makemigrations loads the app, so this was attempting to query a model that had new fields before the migration was created or applied. You can see if this is happening for you by checking the stack trace...

Answer (score 0):

If you only see this error when running tests and you always run tests with the [`--keepdb` flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-keepdb) on, consider removing the flag.

```bash
# From `python manage.py test --keepdb` to:
python manage.py test
```

The `--keepdb` flag will preserve the test database between test runs. If you performed migrations that add/remove columns and you run tests with `--keepdb` flag still on, it will load the preserved test database with an outdated schema instead of creating a new test database with the latest schema.

Answer (score 0):

This steps make it work for me

**WARNING: this actions remove all data in that table(model)**

1. Comment or remove model that have conflict
2. Run `pyhton manage.py makemigrations`
3. Run `pyhton manage.py migrate`
4. Uncomment or rewrite removed model
5. Run `pyhton manage.py makemigrations`
6. Run `pyhton manage.py migrate`

Answer (score -1):

These are the potential reasons why you encounter that problem:

Check Migrations

- Make sure that you've applied the migrations with your application name at the end

`python manage.py makemigrations app-name`

Validate Database Schema

- Confirm that the database schema aligns with the model definitions within your Django application. Utilize a suitable database tool or query to examine the actual schema.

Retry Migration

- In case there is suspicion of an issue with a specific migration, attempt to roll back to a previous migration and then reapplied migrations.

```
python manage.py migrate app_name zero  # Rollback all migrations
python manage.py migrate                # Apply migrations again
```

Correct Definitions

- Double-check for any typos in your model definitions, particularly in field names. Maintain consistency between your model and database naming conventions.

Verify Database Connection:

- Validate that your Django application has established connectivity with the correct database and that relevant settings in your settings.py file are accurate.

Resetting the Entire Database (last resort):

- If all else fails and data loss can be tolerated, it may be necessary to completely reset the database before reapplying migrations

`python manage.py flush`

Answer (score -4):

Solved this issue by running
python manage.py migrate
in Heroku Bash shell