# why column blog_post.category_id does not exist in django after hosting with heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm making a web application with django and I can run this application on localserver without any error.But when I host it gets a error like

> column blog_post.category_id does not exist
> LINE 1: ...d_on", "blog_post"."status", "blog_post"."image", "blog_post...

By the way I run migrations for this application with heroku server.And also when I list tables in heroku using `heroku pg:psql` this command.After that I can see all the tables are created in heroku server.Do you have any suggestion.

And after I run `heroku logs --tail` its gives me like

```
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689478+00:00 app[web.1]: len_values = len(values)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689479+00:00 app[web.1]: self._fetch_all()
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689479+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689479+00:00 app[web.1]: self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689480+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689480+00:00 app[web.1]: results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689480+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689481+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689481+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689482+00:00 app[web.1]: return super().execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689483+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689489+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: return executor(sql, params, many, context)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689491+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689491+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column blog_post.category_id does not exist
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689491+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...d_on", "blog_post"."status", "blog_post"."image", "blog_post...
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689492+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689492+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-31T16:32:23.690341+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.169.135 - - [31/Aug/2021:16:32:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 201041 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
2021-08-31T16:32:23.698152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dtblogsite.herokuapp.com request_id=b69c589b-d071-4829-89c3-c73d43c0c0d4 fwd="123.231.87.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=175ms status=500 bytes=201308 protocol=https
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523536+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523575+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523577+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523577+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523578+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column blog_post.category_id does not exist
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523578+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...d_on", "blog_post"."status", "blog_post"."image", "blog_post...
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523579+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523580+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523580+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523580+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523580+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523581+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523581+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523581+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523582+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523582+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response.render()
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523582+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523583+00:00 app[web.1]: self.content = self.rendered_content
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523583+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523583+00:00 app[web.1]: return template.render(context, self._request)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523583+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523584+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.template.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523584+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523584+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523584+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523585+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.nodelist.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523585+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523585+00:00 app[web.1]: bit = node.render_annotated(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523585+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: return compiled_parent._render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.nodelist.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: bit = node.render_annotated(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: result = block.nodelist.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: bit = node.render_annotated(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: len_values = len(values)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523589+00:00 app[web.1]: self._fetch_all()
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523589+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523589+00:00 app[web.1]: self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523589+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523589+00:00 app[web.1]: results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523590+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523590+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523590+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523590+00:00 app[web.1]: return super().execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523590+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523591+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523597+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523597+00:00 app[web.1]: return executor(sql, params, many, context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523597+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523598+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523598+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523598+00:00 app[web.1]: raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523598+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523598+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523599+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column blog_post.category_id does not exist
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523599+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...d_on", "blog_post"."status", "blog_post"."image", "blog_post...
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523599+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523599+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-31T16:46:19.524235+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.153.32 - - [31/Aug/2021:16:46:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 201046 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
2021-08-31T16:46:19.540018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dtblogsite.herokuapp.com request_id=7a38fa71-9bea-4af1-b155-95ca423aa50f fwd="123.231.87.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=301ms status=500 bytes=201313 protocol=https
^C
(test) dtheekshana@dinindu-linux:~/Desktop/python/django/Django_blog$ heroku logs --tail
(node:224586) SyntaxError Plugin: heroku: /home/dtheekshana/.local/share/heroku/config.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
module: @oclif/config@1.17.0
task: runHook prerun
plugin: heroku
root: /snap/heroku/4076
See more details with DEBUG=*
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689478+00:00 app[web.1]: len_values = len(values)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689479+00:00 app[web.1]: self._fetch_all()
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689479+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689479+00:00 app[web.1]: self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689480+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689480+00:00 app[web.1]: results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689480+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689481+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689481+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689482+00:00 app[web.1]: return super().execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689483+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689489+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: return executor(sql, params, many, context)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689490+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689491+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689491+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column blog_post.category_id does not exist
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689491+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...d_on", "blog_post"."status", "blog_post"."image", "blog_post...
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689492+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-08-31T16:32:23.689492+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-31T16:32:23.690341+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.169.135 - - [31/Aug/2021:16:32:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 201041 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
2021-08-31T16:32:23.698152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dtblogsite.herokuapp.com request_id=b69c589b-d071-4829-89c3-c73d43c0c0d4 fwd="123.231.87.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=175ms status=500 bytes=201308 protocol=https
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523536+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523575+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523577+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523577+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523578+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column blog_post.category_id does not exist
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523578+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...d_on", "blog_post"."status", "blog_post"."image", "blog_post...
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523579+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523580+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523580+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523580+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523580+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523581+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523581+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523581+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523582+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523582+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response.render()
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523582+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523583+00:00 app[web.1]: self.content = self.rendered_content
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523583+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523583+00:00 app[web.1]: return template.render(context, self._request)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523583+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523584+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.template.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523584+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523584+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523584+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523585+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.nodelist.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523585+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523585+00:00 app[web.1]: bit = node.render_annotated(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523585+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: return compiled_parent._render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.nodelist.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523586+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: bit = node.render_annotated(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: result = block.nodelist.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523587+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: bit = node.render_annotated(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.render(context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: len_values = len(values)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523588+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523589+00:00 app[web.1]: self._fetch_all()
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523589+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523589+00:00 app[web.1]: self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523589+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523589+00:00 app[web.1]: results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523590+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523590+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523590+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523590+00:00 app[web.1]: return super().execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523590+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523591+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523597+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523597+00:00 app[web.1]: return executor(sql, params, many, context)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523597+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523598+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523598+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523598+00:00 app[web.1]: raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523598+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523598+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523599+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column blog_post.category_id does not exist
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523599+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...d_on", "blog_post"."status", "blog_post"."image", "blog_post...
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523599+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-08-31T16:46:19.523599+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-31T16:46:19.524235+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.153.32 - - [31/Aug/2021:16:46:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 201046 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
2021-08-31T16:46:19.540018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dtblogsite.herokuapp.com request_id=7a38fa71-9bea-4af1-b155-95ca423aa50f fwd="123.231.87.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=301ms status=500 bytes=201313 protocol=https
```

Comment: Can u post `heroku logs --tail `

Comment: @FaisalNazik you meat whole code of that

Comment: No not all of code, just logs

Comment: @FaisalNazik `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column blog_post.category_id does not exis`  `LINE 1: ...d_on", "blog_post"."status", "blog_post"."image", "blog_post...`

Comment: Are you using the same db engine on the local machine ? Postgres ?

Comment: Sometimes just Error promp is not enough to get the idea, Can u run `heroku logs --tail` command in the terminal, this will give full traceback maybe that would be helpful to pick up the prob.

Comment: @Rvector yeah I use postgresql for local

Comment: @FaisalNazik I updated the answer with heroku logs can you check that out

Comment: This seems just a `db `migration issue, not very sure

Comment: Do you have any suggestion insread of `python manage.py makemigrations`,`python manage.py migrate`,`python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`.

Comment: If had that prob, I would definitely drop the db and then migrate it after resetting it again. if I remember correctly I never used `migrate --run-syncdb`, It creates tables for apps without migrations

Comment: Maybe these answers would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613536/django-programming-error-column-does-not-exist-even-after-running-migrations