# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column tickets_ticket.track_code does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I used postgresql and I want add a new field to my model:

```
track_code = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_('کد رهگیری'), default=generate_rrr_unique_trackcode)
```

but after migrate i received this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column tickets_ticket.track_code does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "tickets_ticket" WHERE "tickets_ticke...
```

I used the command:

```
python3 manage.py migrate app_name 0001
```

and delete the last migration file and then try again but not working...

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42614147/14457833). This may help you to  overcome your problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is wrong command which is you used to migrate.

Migrate using below 3 commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 #This value will generate after makemigrations. It can be either 0001, 0002 and so on

python manage.py migrate
```

Note: don't forget to delete that last migration.

Comment: Thanks but I received same error after step two!

Comment: ok do one thing, delete all migrations file and db file and then try above commands

Comment: Thanks I had to delete my postgres database and create again and then migrate... this is worked!